# Prettyfaces how to rewrite two different view-id with one pattern

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I have two different view-id

/faces/rcg/index.xhtml 
and 
/faces/MasterRiskManager/index.xhtml
Is it possible to rewrite them both with one pattern /inex.html?

Answer (score 0):

No. How would PrettyFaces know which page to rewrite the incoming /index.html as?

If your idea is to rewrite /index.html to one page or the other depending on other factors such as get or post params, you could just choose one then make the redirect decision in that page (using an f:event tag) in a PreRenderViewEvent handler.